# PHP url variables

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<body>
<p> Hello. </p>
<? $d="0"; ?>
<? if($d=="1"){ echo "D equals 1";} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put the above code into a file named test.php. However, when I go to sitename.com/test.php?d=1, it won't echo anything. Is my code wrong, or is there something in the php.ini I need to change? How can I fix this?

Comment: The behavior you are looking for is called [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) and you _should NOT BE USING IT_.  What you want is `if (isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d'] == 1)`

Comment: Read [about the `$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)  If you saw in a book or tutorial that it is possible to directly access `$d` from `test.php?d=1`, you are _very strongly_ advised to find a more up to date resource.

Comment: Ya, sorry about that I am reading php for DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> Hello. </p>
<?php $d = $_GET['d'] ?>
<?php if($d=="1"){ echo "D equals 1";} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: or, in a more readable way:

```
<?php
   $d = $_GET['d'];
   if ($d == '1') {
      echo 'D equals 1';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues:

First, you declare $d and set it to 0 immediately before checking to see if it is 1.

Second, to get the value of a GET variable, use $_GET['d'] instead of just $d.

Answer (score 0):

$phpVariable = $_GET['URL-VARIABLE-NAME'];